# Formula: Possible loss of precision

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that can compute the grade of students, Lab and Nonlab subject.
This is what I've made so far,

```
    String nonlab,lab,choices;
    String quiz1,recitation1,act1,exam1;
    int choice;
    int q1,r1,a1,e1,cs1,gr1,eq1,LAB,lec,six;

    System.out.println("CHOOSE GRADE COMPUTATION");
    System.out.println("[1] NON-LAB COMPUTATION");
    System.out.println("[2] LAB SUBJECT");

    System.out.print("ENTER YOUR CHOICE: ");
    choices=input.readLine();
    choice=Integer.parseInt(choices);

    System.out.println("     ");

    //NON LAB
    if (choice==1){
        System.out.println("******* BEGIN COMPUTATION *******");


    System.out.print("ENTER QUIZ: ");
    quiz1=input.readLine();
        q1=Integer.parseInt(quiz1);

    System.out.print("ENTER RECITATION: ");
    recitation1=input.readLine();
        r1=Integer.parseInt(recitation1);

    System.out.print("ENTER ACTIVITY: ");
    act1=input.readLine();
        a1=Integer.parseInt(act1);

    System.out.print("ENTER MAJOR EXAM: ");
    exam1=input.readLine();
        e1=Integer.parseInt(exam1);

    System.out.println("     ");
    System.out.println("********** RESULT ***************");

    cs1 = (q1+r1+a1)/3;
    gr1 = ((cs1*2)+e1)/3;

    System.out.println("CLASS STANDING: "+cs1);
    System.out.println("GRADE: "+ gr1);
    System.out.print("EQUIVALENT: ");
        if (gr1>97)
            System.out.println("1.00");
        else if (gr1>=94)
            System.out.println("1.25");
        else if (gr1>=91)
            System.out.println("1.50");
        else if (gr1>=88)
            System.out.println("1.75");
        else if (gr1>=85)
            System.out.println("2.00");
        else if (gr1>=82)
            System.out.println("2.25");
        else if (gr1>=79)
            System.out.println("2.50");
        else if (gr1>=76)
            System.out.println("2.75");
        else if (gr1<=75)
            System.out.println("5.00");

    System.out.print("REMARKS: ");
        if (e1<75)
        System.out.println("FAILED");
            else if (e1>75)
        System.out.println("PASSED");
        }

    //LAB SUBJECT
    else if (choice==2){
            System.out.println("******* BEGIN COMPUTATION *******");


    System.out.print("ENTER QUIZ: ");
    quiz1=input.readLine();
        q1=Integer.parseInt(quiz1);

    System.out.print("ENTER RECITATION: ");
    recitation1=input.readLine();
        r1=Integer.parseInt(recitation1);

    System.out.print("ENTER ACTIVITY: ");
    act1=input.readLine();
        a1=Integer.parseInt(act1);

    System.out.print("ENTER MAJOR EXAM: ");
    exam1=input.readLine();
        e1=Integer.parseInt(exam1);

    System.out.println("     ");
    System.out.println("********** RESULT ***************");

    cs1 = (q1+r1)/2;
    lec = ((cs1*2)+e1)/3;
    six = lec*(0.60);
    LAB = a1*(0.40);
    gr1 = 60%+LAB;


    System.out.println("CLASS STANDING: "+cs1);
    System.out.println("GRADE: "+ gr1);
    System.out.print("EQUIVALENT: ");
        if (gr1>97)
            System.out.println("1.00");
        else if (gr1>=94)
            System.out.println("1.25");
        else if (gr1>=91)
            System.out.println("1.50");
        else if (gr1>=88)
            System.out.println("1.75");
        else if (gr1>=85)
            System.out.println("2.00");
        else if (gr1>=82)
            System.out.println("2.25");
        else if (gr1>=79)
            System.out.println("2.50");
        else if (gr1>=76)
            System.out.println("2.75");
        else if (gr1<=75)
            System.out.println("5.00");

    System.out.print("REMARKS: ");
        if (e1<75)
        System.out.println("FAILED");
            else if (e1>75)
        System.out.println("PASSED");
    }
    else (choice>=3)
        System.out.println("WRONG ENTRY!");


}
```

}

I've been receiving an error which says: are not a statement

```
        else (choice>=3)
             ^
';' expected
        else (choice>=3)
```

... When I tried removing the else statement, these are the errors that appear:

```
possible loss of precision
found   : double
required: int

six = lec*(0.60);
          ^

possible loss of precision
found   : double
required: int

    LAB = a1*(0.40);
                ^
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: why do you tag javascript again? this is not java script .this question has been asked lot of time .search the error "possible loss of precision "

Answer (score 0):

You have declared LAB,lec,six as integer values.
Performing floating point number operations on integer is causing that error.
Simply typecast your result of floating point operation before assigning the value back to int.

Solution 1: six = (int)lec*(0.60);

Ideally, you should declare six and lec as double.

Answer (score 0):

1. There should be no condition in else. If you want to introduce a condition use else if.

so modify the statement to `else if(condition>3)System.out.println("WRONG ENTRY!");

2. Possible loss of precision: Throughout your program you are using integers while operations like divisions where there is a possibility of a float result.

IN the examples you mentioned, you can simply cast the resultant floating point numbers from `double` into `int`.

```
int six = (int) (lec*(0.6));
```

But, in general stay advised that many variables in line below could be better used as `float` or `double`.

```
int q1,r1,a1,e1,cs1,gr1,eq1,LAB,lec,six;
```